# Access property of secret without saving it to a variable first?

Tags: serverless-framework

I do this to use a secret:

```
  newRelicLicenseSecret: ${ssm:/aws/reference/secretsmanager/NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY~true}
  newRelic:
    accountId: ${self:custom.newRelicLicenseSecret.NrAccountId}
```

Is there some syntax that would allow me to access `NrAccountId` in `newRelic.accountId` without having to declare `newRelicLicenseSecret`?